# Input format for Tensorflow models on GCP AI Platform

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

I have a uploaded a model to GCP AI Platform Models. It's a simple Keras, Multistep Model, with 5 features trained on 168 lagged values. When I am trying to test the models in, I'm getting this strange error message:

```
  "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:\n\tstatus = StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION\n\tdetails = \"Error while reading resource variable dense_7/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/dense_7/bias)\n\t [[{{node model_2/dense_7/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp}}]]\"\n\tdebug_error_string = \"{\"created\":\"@1618946146.138507164\",\"description\":\"Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:8081\",\"file\":\"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc\",\"file_line\":1061,\"grpc_message\":\"Error while reading resource variable dense_7/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/dense_7/bias)\\n\\t [[{{node model_2/dense_7/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp}}]]\",\"grpc_status\":9}\"\n>"
```

The input is on the following format, a list ((1, 168, 5))

See below of example:

```
{
"instances": 
[[[ 3.10978284e-01,  2.94650396e-01,  8.83664149e-01,
          1.60210423e+00, -1.47402699e+00],
        [ 3.10978284e-01,  2.94650396e-01,  5.23466315e-01,
          1.60210423e+00, -1.47402699e+00],
        [ 8.68576328e-01,  7.78699823e-01,  2.83334426e-01,
          1.60210423e+00, -1.47402699e+00]]]
}
```